# Update-problem timescaledb from 2.2.1 to 2.3.0

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I'm trying to update timescaledb from 2.2.1 to 2.3.0

But when enter the following: **ALTER EXTENSION timescaledb UPDATE;**

I get this error msg:

```
"ERROR:  extension "timescaledb" cannot be updated after the old version has already been loaded
HINT:  Start a new session and execute ALTER EXTENSION as the first command. Make sure to pass the "-X" flag to psql."

psql -X -U postgres -h localhost -d zabbix
```

---

```
zabbix=> \dx timescaledb

timescaledb | 2.2.1   | public | Enables scalable inserts and complex queries for time-series data
(1 row)
```

---

```
zabbix=> SELECT default_version, installed_version FROM pg_available_extensions
where name = 'timescaledb';

 default_version | installed_version 

 2.3.0           | 2.2.1
(1 row)
```

It's a replica. I think i have to change it some other way maybe.

Comment: Do you have the extension in `shared_preload_libraries`, so that it gets loaded at system start?

Comment: yes - shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_stat_statements,auto_explain,timescaledb'

Answer (score 0):

Remove `timescaledb` from `shared_preload_libraries` and restart PostgreSQL.

Then the extension is not loaded, and you can upgrade it.

Afterwards, add the library to `shared_preload_libraries` again and restart again.

Comment: Ok now i have updated on the primary. Do i need to do something on the two replicas? They are still using the older version. Thanks for the support!

Comment: If you updated the primary, the standbys are automatically updated. Perhaps you have a replication problem. Consult the log.

Comment: Ok will check. Thanks!